# Android Listview in PopupWindow onitemclick not work on some device

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener, android-popupwindow

My ListView is inside PopupWindow.

When i shown PopupWindow and click on Listview row in device ASUS K00z fonepad worke very well.

But in HTC Z715e is not working (onitem click event not fired)

1.This is my listview item layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ln_testpopitemcon"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:background="#3b8ed4"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_testiconmenu"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/radio_selected"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_testtitlemenu"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

2.This is my popup layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ln_testpopocontainer"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/lv_testpop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

3.This is my adapter

```
public class testmenuadapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<MenuInfo> MenuList;
    private LayoutInflater Layf;

    public testmenuadapter(Context context, ArrayList<MenuInfo> menuList){
        this.context = context;
        this.MenuList = menuList;
        this.Layf = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MenuList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return MenuList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = Layf.inflate(R.layout.testpopoitem, null);

            holder.img_testiconmenu = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_testiconmenu);
            holder.tv_testtitlemenu = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_testtitlemenu);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        MenuInfo info = MenuList.get(position);

        if(info != null) {
            if (holder.tv_testtitlemenu != null) {
                holder.tv_testtitlemenu.setText(info.getTitle());
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView img_testiconmenu;
        TextView tv_testtitlemenu;
    }
}
```

4.This is code i use to create and show popup

```
final View actionview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testpopo, (ViewGroup)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ln_testpopocontainer));
this.testpopup = new PopupWindow(actionview, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
this.testpopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
this.testpopup.setOutsideTouchable(false);
this.testpopup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);

this.testpopuplistview = (ListView)this.testpopup.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.lv_testpop);

this.testmenupopup = new ArrayList<MenuInfo>();
this.testmenupopup.add(new MenuInfo("aaa", "AAA", 0, 0, false));
this.testmenupopup.add(new MenuInfo("bbb", "BBB", 0, 0, false));
this.testmenupopup.add(new MenuInfo("ccc", "CCC", 0, 0, false));

this.testpopadapter = new testmenuadapter(getActivity(), this.testmenupopup);

this.testpopuplistview.setAdapter(this.testpopadapter);
this.testpopuplistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ((MenuInfo)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position)).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

Button btnshowpop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_showpop);
btnshowpop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        testpopup.showAtLocation(rootView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
});
```

How to solve it's

**EDIT
i can solve my problem.**

replace

```
this.testpopup = new PopupWindow(actionview, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

with

```
this.testpopup = new PopupWindow(actionview, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
```

sorry for waste time i'm very stupid.

Comment: i can solve my problem please see under edit in question.

Comment: Thank you soo much, i was scratching my head from two days, and finally i got your solution, it works awesome.

Comment: Thank's! it saved my time

Answer (score 3):

You can make context menu instead of popup menu it work same like this .
For creating context menu just refer this link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu

In this link refer to `Creating Contextual Menus`.

Sort exanple on this like this u can add context menu ------
first register it in onclicklistener like

registerForContextMenu(view)

```
for oncreate  
    @Override     
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)  
 {  
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_UNPAIR_ITEM, Menu.NONE, "UNPAIR");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, DEFAULT_DEVICE, Menu.NONE, "USE AS CGM DEVICE");        
    }

For item selected in context menu  
@Override  
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)  
{  
 switch (item.getItemId())  
{  
 case CONTEXT_MENU_UNPAIR_ITEM:  
 //whatever u want
break  
case DEFAULT_DEVICE:  
 //whatever your logic accordind to u  
return(true);  
}  
return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use **ListAdapter** instead of **BaseAdapter** for a **ListView** , and return True for **areAllItemsEnabled** and **isItemEnabled** in the class that implements ListAdapter.

Something like this...

```
class CustomListAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    Activity callingActivity;
    ArrayList<String> items;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity act, ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        callingActivity = act;
        items = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) { 
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(callingActivity);
        ll.setLayoutParams(params);
        ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        ll.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        //
        // Code for your list item here...
        //

        return ll;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Good Luck. :)