# Android ListView's OnItemClickListener not working on non-focusable PopupWindow

Tags: android, listview, popupwindow, onitemclicklistener

In my Android app I have an `EditText`. When the `EditText` is focused, a `PopupWindow` is shown, which contains a `ListView`. The user can continue typing in the `EditText` when the `PopupWindow` is on screen, and in the mean time he/she should be able to click an item on the `ListView` to dismiss the `PopupWindow`. (Depending on which `ListView` item is clicked, in addition to dismissing the `PopupWindow` something else should also happen, but it's irrelevant here.)

The problem is, although the "continue typing" part works, the "click an item" part doesn't, because the `OnItemClickListener` of the `ListView` never gets called, and I can't figure out why.

Here's my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ddd"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context="com.example.popuptest3.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My `popup_window.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDismiss"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Dismiss" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My `list_item.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Item Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my `MainActivity` class I have the following preparation code:

```
private PopupWindow popup = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    prepareControls();
}

private void prepareControls() {
    final EditText edtPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
    edtPhone.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus)
                openPopup(edtPhone);
            else
                closePopup();
        }
    });
}
```

That is, I open the `PopupWindow` when `edtPhone` gets focus, and close the `PopupWindow` when `edtPhone` loses focus. Then I have:

```
private void openPopup(View parent) {
    closePopup();

    // Inflate the view of the PopupWindow.
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window,
            new LinearLayout(this), false);
    final Activity activity = this;

    // Prepare the ListView.
    ListView lstItems = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lstItems);
    lstItems.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));
    lstItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            hideKeyboardAndClearFocus(activity);
        }
    });

    // Prepare the Button.
    Button btnDismiss = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnDismiss);
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hideKeyboardAndClearFocus(activity);
        }
    });

    // Create and show the PopupWindow.
    popup = new PopupWindow(view, 400, 300, false);
    popup.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP, 0, 60);
}
```

The `btnDismiss` button is not part of my plan; I add it here just for demonstration purposes. Finally I have:

```
private void closePopup() {
    if (popup != null) {
        popup.dismiss();
        popup = null;
    }
}

private static void hideKeyboardAndClearFocus(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)activity.
            getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().clearFocus();
}
```

I think this doesn't require explanation, and the `ListAdapter` class is quite standard so I omit it.

Now, when I click on `edtPhone`, it gets focus, the soft keyboard shows up, and the `PopupWindow` opens. I can type something into `edtPhone`, and when I click on `btnDismiss`, `edtPhone` loses focus, the soft keyboard is dismissed, and the `PopupWindow` closes, all as expected. But if instead of `btnDismiss` I click on an item on `lstItems`, nothing happens. Using `Log` I can see that `OnItemClickListener` is not called. The funny thing is, the `ListView` can be scrolled well, it just cannot be clicked.

I know [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696597/android-listview-in-popupwindow-onitemclick-not-work-on-some-device) but that solution doesn't work for my purpose. If I change this line:

```
popup = new PopupWindow(view, 400, 300, false);
```

to the following:

```
popup = new PopupWindow(view, 400, 300, true);
```

the `PopupWindow` becomes focusable and the `ListView` becomes clickable, alright, but then I cannot continue typing into `edtPhone`. In fact, if there are other controls on the activity, they all become unreachable, as if the `PopupWindow` is "modal".

I also tried `android:focusable="false"`, no luck. And I'm not doing auto-complete so `AutoCompleteTextView` isn't what I need.

So why is `OnItemClickListener` not called on non-focusable `PopupWindow`? Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the popupwindow to non-focusable

```
popupwindow.setFocusable(false);
popupwindow.setTouchable(true);
popupwindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

extend the ListView and override the following methods

```
@Override
public boolean hasFocus() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isFocused() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean hasWindowFocus() {
    return true;
}
```

This is how AutoCompleteTextView implements the popup for suggestions.
If you need to select the list item using DPAD keys or other navigation keys , then you need to pass the key events from the EditText to the ListView.

Comment: It was quite a while ago, and I have moved on, so I'm afraid I can't verify your answer now. But I understand what you suggest, and I think you are right, so I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this just solved the same problem for me, an onItemLongClickListener not getting called from a  ListView inside a popupWindow.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by just setting an `OnClickListener` on `convertview`, which is a parameter of adapter's `getView` method. I then calls `onItemClick` method of the listview's onItemClickListener.

**No need to make popupWindow focusable**. **Infact, just using ListPopupWindow is easier since its only inside `getView()` adapter method that we are adding some few lines of code**

```
ListPopupWindow popupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(mContext);

    MentionsAdapter adapter = new MentionsAdapter(mContext, suggestions);
    popupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String username = mSuggestions.get(position);
            String mentionCompletion = username.substring(mCurrentQuery.length()).concat(" ");
            mEditor.getText().insert(mEditor.getSelectionEnd(), mentionCompletion);
            hideSuggestions();
        }
    });
   popupWindow.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`MentionsAdapter` `getView` method

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(,R.layout.item_user,parent,false);

        }
        // this is the key point of workaround
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               popupWindow.getListView().getOnItemClickListener()
                 .onItemClick(listView, v, position, getItemId(position));
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```